# Android cursor no step more than 1 record

Tags: android, cursor

My query return 198 registers but cursor only read one register.
Why?

The *mCount* property of *Cursor* show 198.

This code:

```
    public ArrayList<EnderecoOficina> retornarListaEnderecoOficina(String sCampo,
                                                               String sWhere) {
    ArrayList<EnderecoOficina> lista = new ArrayList<EnderecoOficina>();
    String query = String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s",
            sCampo,
            MyDBConstants.TABLE_OFICINAS,
            sWhere);

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    int i = 0;
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        EnderecoOficina item = new EnderecoOficina(i++,
                cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2));
        lista.add(item);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return  lista;
}
```

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZYsU.jpg) (my points not allow attach image here).

Comment: use this method getCount() of Cursor to get the number of rows in your case : cursor.getCount()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing `while` syntax.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Will loop without doing anything until the `Cursor` is empty. I think you wanted a do/while as explained by [CommonsWare answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29583113/898478).

In my opinion, this is an unnecessary complicated way to do it. A lot of people don't know how to use Android `Cursor`. I've seen all kinds of complicated ways to do it (checking for null, moving to first, moving to index...), but this is the simplest way:

```
try {
    // Loop while there are records on the Cursor
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       EnderecoOficina item = new EnderecoOficina(i++,
                cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2));
        lista.add(item);
    }
} finally {
    // Make sure the cursor is closed no matter what
    cursor.close();
}
```

There's no need to check for null, Android Cursor API never returns a null cursor. You also need to close the Cursor once you've finished with it.